# Split by /* act as regex?

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

My code looks like below,

```
string filename  = '/*testfile /*testfile';

List<String> parts = filename.split('/*');
```

Expected output  :

```
testfile

testfile
```

Output received:

```
t 

e

s
..
```

Comment: Are you trying to parse the comments? Because they should terminate with `*/` , not another `/*`. Also you ignore `//` style comments with this approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Split actually expects a *regular expression*, so your split string is interpreted as "split when there are zero or more / characters" ("*" means "zero or more").

To avoid this behavior, you have to "escape" the "*" character with a backslash, which itself needs to be escaped with a backslash:

```
List<String> parts = filename.split('/\\*');
```

Without that escape, it tries to split every character from every other character, with the slash ("/") being stripped out entirely.

If you look at the [String methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm), the documentation tells you this explicitly:

> ## split(regExp)
>
> Returns a list that contains each substring of the String that matches this pattern.
>
> ### Signature
>
> ```
> public String[] split(String regExp)
> ```